# button does not display alert box in jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp

i want to have a button in my table and when i press that button i want a alert or message to appear.i have tried  onclick event but still it does not work.. this is my code..the alert is in the last column

```
<%   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/engbooks","root","");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from books");
        while(rs.next()){
            out.print("<tr><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(1)+"</td><td style='border-style: solid;'><a onclick=incq('d','"+ rs.getString(3)+"')>remove</a>    "+rs.getString(11)+"   <a onclick=incq('g','"+ rs.getString(3)+"')>add</a></td><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(2)+"</td><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(4)+"</td><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(6)+"</td><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(7)+"</td><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(8)+"</td><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(9)+"</td><td style='border-style: solid;'>"+rs.getString(10)+"</td><td><img src='image1.jsp?imgid="+ rs.getString(1)+ "&imgid1="+ rs.getString(3)+ "' width='50' height='50'></td></td><td style='border-style: solid;'>  <input type=submit  value=buy onclick="alert('')"> </td></tr>");
        }            
        %>
```

please help me and tell me if i am not clear

Comment: You're not supposed to use `out.print` like this in JSP, this makes your code barely readable and lead to quote related bugs.

Comment: Can you post rendered html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `<input type=submit  value=buy onclick="alert('')">`

to

`<input type="button"  value="buy" onclick=\"alert('')\">`

Comment: i tried it but there is a syntax error...Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  MethodInvocation

Comment: @user3114386 see updated answer. Double quotes have to be escaped. that causes syntax error

Comment: but buy should be within single quotes

Comment: Yes, it can be either single quote or double quote. If you are using double quotes, it should be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

try by updating with following code

```
<a onclick=\"javascript:incq('g','"+rs.getString(3)+"');\">add</a>
```

and let me know if you face any issues

Comment: i m not facing any issue in that part..i want to display the alert message for a button which is present in the last column of the table row

Comment: ok for value field in button you haven't added ' it might be the reason check

Comment: <td style='border-style: solid;'>  <input type=submit  value=buy onclick="alert('')"> </td></tr>

Comment: <td style='border-style: solid;'> <input type=submit value='buy' onclick="alert('')"> </td></tr>

Comment: a button with buy is displayed in my web app..but nothing happens when i click it

Comment: try this <td style='border-style: solid;'> <input type=submit value='buy' onclick="javascript:alert('test');"> </td></tr>

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code should work

```
   <%   
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/engbooks","root","");
        Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from books");
        while(rs.next()){
            %>

            <tr><td style='border-style: solid;'> <%=rs.getString(1)%>
            </td><td style='border-style: solid;'> <a onclick="incq('d',<%=rs.getString(3)%>)">remove</a>    
             <%=rs.getString(11)%>   <a onclick=incq('g','<%=rs.getString(3) %>')>add</a></td>

             <td style='border-style: solid;'> <%=rs.getString(2)%></td>
             <td style='border-style: solid;'><%=rs.getString(4)%> </td>
             <td style='border-style: solid;'><%=rs.getString(6)%> </td>
             <td style='border-style: solid;'><%=rs.getString(7)%></td>
             <td style='border-style: solid;'><%=rs.getString(8)%></td>
             <td style='border-style: solid;'><%=rs.getString(9)%></td>
             <td style='border-style: solid;'><%=rs.getString(10)%></td>
             <td><img src='image1.jsp?imgid=<%=rs.getString(1)%>&imgid1=<%=rs.getString(3)%>' width='50' height='50'>
             </td>
             </td>
             <td style='border-style: solid;'>  
         <input type=submit  value=buy onclick="alert('')"> </td></tr>");
       <% 
          }            
        %>
```